# "Not Now" button handling in **Facebook-SDK**

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

In **Facebook-Login** when user enters "Username & Password" then on safari **Facebook-SDK** showing below screen. [image]

If the user clicks on **Not Now** rather that on **Continue as User**. **Facebook-SDK** returns always **Success**

> Is this **Facebook-SDK** bug or I am missing something.

I am adding below code:

```
func fbLoginWithViewController(viewController :UIViewController, completion : @escaping (_ loginResult: AnyObject, _ error: NSError?) -> Void) {
        let  loginManager = LoginManager()
        loginManager.loginBehavior = .systemAccount
        loginManager.logIn([ .publicProfile,.userFriends,.email ], viewController: viewController) { loginResult in
            switch loginResult {
            case .failed(let error):
                print(error)
                // show error method
                self.isCancelled = false
                completion(loginResult as AnyObject,error as NSError?)
            case .cancelled:
                print("User cancelled login.")
                // show cancelled error
                self.isCancelled = true
                completion(loginResult as AnyObject,nil)

            case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
                print("Logged in!")

                //add api
                self.isCancelled = false

                if((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil){
                    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, email, picture.width(180).height(180)"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                        if (error == nil){
                            self.fbAccesstoken = FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString
                            completion(result as AnyObject,nil)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Let me know if I am doing wrong!

Comment: Is the user completely cancelling login here, or are they just denying that specific permission? If the user has logged in to the app before already, then I think Facebook does not consider this scenario a cancelled login.

Comment: @CBroe In all cases if user clicks on "Not Now" it returns users whole object , accessToken, useremail etc